# Finding volume triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume of the solid enclosed on the outside of the sphere $r=2$ and on the inside by the surface $r=1+\cos\phi$.

I am not sure how to set it up.

Comment: A bit more context could be given before anyone sketches an answer... I this from a book? Which one? What topics are you trying to learn? A few other good practices are given on: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: Can you also specify what $\phi$ represents here? I assume it's the polar angle but just want to make sure, as I've seen the $\theta$ and $\phi$ flip-flopped before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $d^3\mathbf{x}=r^2dr\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$, your integral is $$V:=\int_0^\pi\sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{1+\cos\phi}^2 r^2 dr.$$ Since odd powers of $\cos\phi$ will integrate to $0$, $$V=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}(7-3\cos^2\phi)d\phi=\frac{22\pi }{3}.$$